# Post data with libcurl to PHP $_Get

Tags: php, curl, gcc, raspberry-pi, libcurl

the data does not arrive.
Here is the c program on RaspberryPI:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
 
int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://iautos.be/TestMake.php");  
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "d=2020/09/16 16:00:00,21.6,P,");
      
    /* url could be redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
 
    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));
 
    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The target PHP file on the webserver,
This works well in a browser (Firefox):
http://iautos.be/TestMake.php?d=2020/09/14%2004:00:00,21.6,P,

```
<?php
// Program to display URL of current page. 
// Put the host(domain name, ip) to the URL. 
$link = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
// Append the requested resource location to the URL 
$link .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
echo 'Url: ' , $link , "<br/>\n"; 
$Data = array();
$Data = explode(',', trim($_GET['d']) );
for ($x = 0; $x <= 2; $x++) {
      echo 'Data' , $x , ': ' , $Data[$x] , "<br/>\n" ;
}
print "Success.\n";
?>
```

Problem:
When I post data with Firefox it works well. You can test it out (link above).
With libcurl the data is not sent.
What could be wrong ?

Here is the output of the libcurl testprogram on RaspberryPI:

```
Url: iautos.be/TestMake.php<br/>
Data0: <br/>
Data1: <br/>
Data2: <br/>
Success.
```

Here is the output of Firefox:

```
Url: iautos.be/TestMake.php?d=2020/09/14%2004:00:00,21.6,P,
Data0: 2020/09/14 04:00:00
Data1: 21.6
Data2: P
Success.
```

Comment: You're setting `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` but the page seems to expect `GET` variables, not `POST` variables. Have you tried `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://iautos.be/TestMake.php?d=2020/09/14%2004:00:00,21.6,P,");` ?

Answer (score 0):

POSTFIELDS in CURL are sent as a POST to the server, so those parameters will be in the $_POST superglobal array.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am new in this stuff.
I did some more test. This works:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://iautos.be/TestMake.php/?d=2020/09/16%2016:00:00,21.6,P,");
```

Thanks for your help.